# Page style: plain vs empty

Tags: header-footer

What is the difference between between `empty` and `plain` as in `\thispagestyle{empty}` and `\thispagestyle{plain}`?

Are there any more options? What do they differ in?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Standard classes

LaTeX predefines four page styles for standard classes:

- `empty` Both header and footer are empty.
- `plain` The header is empty; the footer contains the page number.
- `headings` The footer is empty; the header contains information determined by the class (based on sectional units) and the page number.
- `myheadings` It is similar to `headings` but the user controls the information in the header.

There is a number of packages that allow the definition of new page styles and/or the redefinition of predefined styles:

- [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).
- [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps).
- [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage).

### memoir

`memoir` offers a greater number of predefined page styles:

- `empty` The headers and footers are empty.
- `plain` The header is empty and the folio (page number) is centered at the bottom of the
  page.
- `headings` The footer is empty. The header contains the folio at the outer side of the page; on verso pages the chapter name, number and title, in slanted uppercase is set at the spine margin and on recto pages the section number and uppercase title is set by the spine margin.
- `myheadings` Like the `headings` style the footer is empty. You have to specify what is to go in the headers.
- `simple` The footer is empty and the header contains the folio (page number) at the outer side of the page. It is like the headings style but without any title texts.
- `ruled` The footer contains the folio at the outside. The header on verso pages contains the
  chapter number and title in small caps at the outside; on recto pges the section title is
  typeset at the outside using the normal font. A line is drawn underneath the header.
- `Ruled` This is like the ruled style except that the headers and footers extend into the fore-
  edge margin.
- `companion` This is a copy of the pagestyle in the Companion series. It is similar to the Ruled style in that the header has a rule which extends to the outer edge of the marginal notes. The folios are set in bold at the outer ends of the header. The chapter title is set in a bold font flushright in the verso headers, and the section number and title, again in bold, flushleft in the recto headers. There are no footers.
- `book` This is the same as the `plain` pagestyle.
- `chapter` This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
- `cleared` This is the same as the empty pagestyle.
- `part` This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
- `title` This is the same as the plain pagestyle.
- `titlingpage` This is the same as the empty pagestyle.

The class offers its own mechanism to (re)define page styles.

### KOMA classes

- `empty` is the page style with entirely empty headers and footers. In KOMA - Script this is completely identical to the standard classes.
- `headings` is the page style with running headings in the header. These are headings for which titles are automatically inserted into the header. With the classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` the titles of chapters and sections are repeated in the header for double-sided layout; with KOMA-Script on the outer side, with the standard classes on the inner side.

  The page number is set on the outer side of the footer with KOMA-Script; with the standard classes it is set on the inner side of the header. In one-sided layouts only the titles of the chapters are used and are, with KOMA - Script, centered in the header. The page numbers are set centered in the footer with KOMA-Script. `scrartcl` behaves similarly, but starting a level deeper in the section hierarchy with sections and subsections, because the chapter level does not exist in this case. While the standard classes automatically set running headings always in capitals, KOMA-Script applies the style of the title.
- `myheadings` corresponds mostly to the page style `headings`, but the running headings are not automatically produced — they have to be defined by the user.
- `plain` is the page style with empty header and only a page number in the footer. With the standard classes this page number is always centered in the footer. With KOMA-Script the page number appears on double-sided layout on the outer side of the footer. The one-sided page style behaves like the standard setup.

KOMA-Script classes support rules below the head and above the foot using the options `headsepline` and `footsepline`.

Although page styles can be (re)defined using `fancyhdr`, a dedicated  package [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) was designed to better integrate with the KOMA-Script bundle. This package is not limited to use only with the KOMA-Script classes, but can just as easily be used with other document classes.

Sources: `memman` and `scrguien`.

Comment: The KOMA packages `scrpage2` and its successor `scrlayer-scrpage` can be used with other classes, too. So »there are two packages that allow...« is not *quite* true :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @cgnieder True. I updated my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I already had voted :) ... you've missed the page style `scrheadings` :) BTW: `scrlayer-scrpage` is the official successor of `scrpage2`. IIRC `scrpage2` isn't even described any more in the latest edition of the KOMA-Script book (at least it's missing in my version of scrguien (2014-07-31)). [`scrlayer-scrpage` is indeed far more capable and flexible.](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5303#5306)

Comment: @cgnieder I'll add `scrheadings` and will also change the `scrpage2` package to `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: I just realized that `\pagestyle{empty}` does not affect the first page on chapters in `scrbook`.

Comment: Encyclopaedic! Very instructive.

Comment: How can I get the folio (page number) on the right side and at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Where should I define it, on the preamble or within the document or section?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, where can I find the definition of the `plain` page style? For example, in `report.cls` we only find the `headings` and `myheadings` ones.

Answer (score 9):

`\thispagestyle{empty}` makes header and footer, well… empty; `plain` just puts a `page number` at the centre of the footer. But you can use any page style that is known to the system, say defined in your preamble with the help of a package like `titleps`, bundled with `titlesec`.

Comment: are there any more options besides `plain` and `empty`?

Comment: They're the same as for `\pagestyle`: `headings` to add headers, and `myheadings`, where it's up to you to declare what exactly goes into the headers. In addition, if you use the `fancyhdr` package, you have the `fancy` page style, that you can re-define; as for `titleps`, it lets you define new page styles or redefine existing page styles.