# fancyhdr package not working

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

So I'm using the `fancyhdr` package and compiling my code and it gives me no error whatsoever but it's not working, it does not display any header or footer and keeps giving me number on the bottom center of the page...
I don't understand what is wrong.
Here is my code below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}\addcontentsline{toc}chapter}{\listtablename}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapter/introduction.tex}
\chapter{Bibliography work}
\input{chapter/bib_work.tex}
\chapter{Material and methods}
\input{chapter/mat_and_meth}
\chapter{Results}
\input{chapter/results}
\chapter{Discussion}
\input{chapter/discussion}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapter/conclusion}
\pagebreak
\nocite{benkaddour_salinite_2011}
\nocite{fetouani_assessing_2008}
\nocite{kihumba_modelling_2016}
\nocite{mattern_bayesian_2012}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\chapter*{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is of course not compilable, since there are a lot of `\input` statements, for files we can't access! `\pagenumbering{...}` always resets the page counter to `1`, no need to `\setcounter{page}{1}` ... and `\chapter*` before `\begin{document}` does not work!

Comment: Those files are empty, it's just for the structure of the thesis now

Comment: Try `\input{Ishouldlearnhowtomakeanmwe}` ... ;-)

Comment: But even without the input, it's not working and I don"t know why...

Comment: There is another typo: `addcontentsline{toc}chapter}{\listtablename}!!! It should read `addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this order:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
[...]
```

Then `fancyhdr` will see the correct margin setting. For the first  chapter page  `LaTeX` automatically uses pagestyle `plain` which has no header and the pagenumber in the bottom centered. Redefine this pagestyle. See documentation of `fancyhdr` for an example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%  the preset of fancyhdr 
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: see edited answer for the other problem.

Answer (score 9):

## Few things to know first

1. `\pagestyle{<style>}` is a LaTeX native command that sets the current style to `<style>`.

   1. LaTeX has four predefined styles: `plain`, `empty`, `headings`, and `myheadings`.

      - Several packages extended the number of predefined styles, such as [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), and [`titleps`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps). Further info [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194423/page-style-plain-vs-empty).
   2. If not set by the class/package, the initial style is `plain`.
2. `\thispagestyle{<style>}` is a LaTeX native command that sets the style of the current page to `<style>`.

   - Classes such as `article`, `book`, or `report` make use of `\thispagestyle{plain}` at `\maketitle`, or `\chapter`.
3. The commands from the [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package, e.g. `\fancyhf{}`, act on the current style.
4. `\fancypagestyle{<style>}{<fancyhdr commands>}` creates a closed environment in which

   1. It first copies the `fancy` style over `<style>`, creating it if necessary;
   2. It then sets `<style>` as the current style;
   3. Finally it modifies `<style>` executing `<fancyhdr commands>`.
   4. Note that the current document style has not changed.
   5. BUG: Do not issue `\fancypagestyle{fancy}{<fancyhdr commands>}`, the LaTeX compiler will hang at the first `\pagestyle{fancy}` call since it will enter in an infinite recursive loop. I just notified the author with regards to this.

## Why your code does not what you intend to?

Once you call `\pagestyle{fancy}`, you have set the current page style to `fancy`, and the subsequent commands will modify this style only. The class you are using, `report`, will issue repeatedly `\thispagestyle{plain}` countering your previous changes.

## How to do what you itend to?

### Option 1 (recommended)

Simply edit the `plain` style. Recommended if you intend to use only one style.

```
\pagestyle{plain} % this line is not necessary if previously no style has been set
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

### Option 2

Edit `fancy` and copy it to `plain`. Edits to `fancy` or `plain` won't affect each other. Recommended if you intend to use different styles.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% copies "fancy" over "plain"
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% you can add edits that won't affect "fancy" but only "plain"
}
```